# Can Junit Ignore annotation be set to specific platforms or environments?

Tags: junit

Is there a standard way to ignore tests just for one platform or environment?

I have a cross platform build which has some junit tests which I only want to ignore on specific platforms.  I figure I can conditionalize the tests a few different ways:

- use categories to disable tests for specific platforms (e.g. NOT_SOLARIS)
- modify Ignore annotation and TestMethod to add Platform option to ignore

  @Ignore("IssueTracker-ID", Ignore.PlatformSOLARIS)

If I choose the second option I will need to alter my local fork of junit (which isn't an issue since I'm already using a modified version).  I can change the Ignore annotation to support a platform key and then change TestMethod.isIgnored to act on the key.

Is there a standard Junit way to handle this kind of situation?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [Assume](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/junit/Assume.java). For example:

```
public void testWindows() {
  assumeTrue(platform != SOLARIS)
}
```